# Merging One Column on to Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have the following two dataframes, DF1:

```
   location     vaccine1            vaccine2          vaccine3           vaccine4
0   Afghanistan Oxford/AstraZeneca  Pfizer/BioNTech   Sinopharm/Beijing  None
1   Albania     Oxford/AstraZeneca  Pfizer/BioNTech   Sinovac            Sputnik V
2   Algeria     Sputnik V           None              None               None
3   Andorra     Oxford/AstraZeneca  Pfizer/BioNTech   None               None
```

DF2:

```
    Vaccine             Efficacy
0   Oxford/AstraZeneca  0.70
1   Pfizer/BioNTech     0.95
2   Sinopharm/Beijing   0.79
3   Sinovac             0.50
4   Sputnik V           0.92
```

I understand that you can merge like this below but the process is repeated 4 times which is inefficient:

```
v1 = pd.merge(df1, vacc_eff, how='left', left_on='vaccine1', right_on='Vaccine')[['location', 'Efficacy']]
v2 = pd.merge(df1, vacc_eff, how='left', left_on='vaccine2', right_on='Vaccine')[['location', 'Efficacy']]

vmerged = pd.merge(v1,v2,on=['location'])
```

How can I merge the DF2 column 'Efficacy' onto each of the vaccine columns in DF1 without writing the same merge function again and again?

Comment: As your `right_on` condition of merge will never change, why not using a `for` loop iterating over the list of `left_on` conditions (in your case `['vaccine1', 'vaccine2', 'vaccine3', vaccine4']`) ?

Comment: kindly post your expected output as a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out, [**stack**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [**map**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) then [**unstack**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas-dataframe-unstack)

```
map_ = vacc_eff.set_index('Vaccine')['Efficacy'].to_dict()

print(
    df1[['location', 'vaccine1', 'vaccine2']].set_index('location')
        .stack().map(map_).unstack()
)
```

---

```
             vaccine1  vaccine2
location                       
Afghanistan      0.70      0.95
Albania          0.70      0.95
Algeria          0.92       NaN
Andorra          0.70      0.95
```